# jQuery Table call td value only text

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table (id="deneme").

I need to iterate through the td value, determine which checkboxes the user has checked, and for the rows with a checked checkbox, grab the value for the only text(literal) of middle column.

Maybe for first letter can be defined an algorithm.

```
<table id="docsTable">
    <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC" class="liste-0">
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>Document Title 1</td>
        <td>567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>accure</td>
        <td>134</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>231</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id='btnTest' value='Get Rows' />
```

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnTest').click(function() {
        $('#docsTable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
            alert($row.find('td:eq(0) input').val());
            alert($row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
            alert($row.find('td:eq(2)').html());
        });
    });
});
```

Demo :

http://www.jsfiddle.net/3yYFY/

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has` and `map` methods and store the values an in array.

```
$('#btnTest').click(function() {
    var arr = $('#docsTable tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
        return $('td:eq(1)', this).text()
    }).get();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twn2W/

Comment: @aldimeola1122 You are welcome, yes, before return you can alert `alert( $('td:eq(1)', this).text() )`

Comment: thanks perfect, but i need to an algorithm, that call only text in a row.
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3yYFY/1/
for an example, in second row = accure, alligator, badger
 in third row = Zebra, Elephant

Answer (score 0):

By what i have understood from your question, you should use closest() instead of find() method

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#docsTable input:checked").closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").map(function () {
  return $(this).text();
}).toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checked')​.parent().next().each(function(){alert($(this).html())})
```